# Setup up site to site VPN between two Windows 2008 servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, vpn

I have two windows 2008R2 servers; one in head office, one in a remote office.  There is a RRAS VPN setup on the head office server that remote users can connect to, and I'd like to change the configuration so the remote users all connect through their windows 2008 server instead of having a VPN connection each.

The two problems I have are:
The remote server has only one network card.  All the examples I can find assume use of two cards and making the server handle all all outbound network traffic. I only want it to handle VPN related traffic while other traffic continues to go out the existing internet firewall.  I can use a route entry to funnel the required traffic to the windows 2008 server, provided it will handle it.

I don't want to reconfigure the remote server to use 192.167.137.1 as its IP address, which is what I am prompted to do if I try to enable sharing on the VPN connection.

Comment: Have you considered creating a site-to-site VPN between the routers at each office?  That would free up the servers to communicate with each other without having to deal with RRAS and server VPN configurations...

Comment: Using routers is the fallback plan because of the time it will take to get the hardware configured and off to the remote office; I would have liked to get things running with the available hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the main server as the VPN server, using a custom RRAS configuration (instead of the standard VPN config).  Turn on the VPN component only.  Then make sure that the server and workstations at your remote site all authenticate to the VPN at startup, and also have the remote default gateway disabled.